# 'el hámster' or 'la hámster' if the hamster is female?

Tags: sustantivos, pronunciación, género, letras

Which definite article ('el' or 'la'?) should be used if a hamster is female ('hembra')?

I know that some spanish speakers pronounce 'hámster' as 'jámster' in which case I imagine that 'la' is used.

However, if 'hámster' is pronounced as 'ámster' then is the definite article 'el' used?

**bonus question:** Do adjectives agree with the gender of the hamster i.e. 'el hámster rubia'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *h* in *hámster* is pronounced like in English or German, that is, as a `/j/`. For this, we say:

- *el hámster*
- *la hámster*

This is explained in Diccionario panhispánico de dudas:

> [**hámster**](https://www.rae.es/dpd/h%C3%A1mster). Voz tomada del alemán *Hamster*, ‘pequeño roedor, semejante a un ratón’. En la pronunciación se mantiene la aspiración etimológica de la *h* inicial (→ h, [2](https://www.rae.es/dpd/h%C3%A1mster?id=MBepIDBpND6YZFRAkx#2)). Su plural debe ser hámsteres (→ plural, 1g): «*Conejos, hámsteres y gallos de pelea*» (Mendoza Satanás [Col. 2002]).

And the link to the [*h, [2]* article](https://www.rae.es/dpd/h#2) explains that this sound of the *h* is how it originally sounded until mid XVI:

> 2. Esta letra no representa, en el español estándar actual, ningún sonido, aunque hasta mediados del siglo xvi se pronunciaba, en determinados casos (concretamente cuando procedía de f inicial latina), de forma parecida a como se pronuncia hoy la h aspirada inglesa. Esta aspiración aún se conserva como rasgo dialectal en Andalucía, Extremadura, Canarias y otras zonas de España y América. A veces, la aspiración llega casi a convertirse en el sonido velar fricativo sordo /j/, pronunciación que en algún caso tiene reflejo en la escritura; así ha ocurrido, por ejemplo, con el adjetivo jondo (‘hondo’, del lat. *fundus*), que se aplica al cante más genuinamente andaluz, caracterizado por su profundo sentimiento, o con el verbo jalar, variante de *halar* usada en varios países americanos, o con jolgorio, grafía hoy mayoritaria frente a la etimológica holgorio. En algunos extranjerismos usados corrientemente en español (tomados, por lo general, del inglés o del alemán, pero también de otras lenguas como el árabe), así como en algunos nombres propios extranjeros y sus derivados, la h se pronuncia también aspirada o con sonido cercano al de /j/: *hámster, holding, hachís, Hawái (hawaiano), Hegel (hegeliano)*, etc.

---

> **bonus question:** Do adjectives agree with the gender of the hamster i.e. 'el hámster rubia'?

Since it is 'la hámster', it would be 'la hámster rubia'. If it was with 'el' it would have been 'rubio', as a masculino.

Comment: For me, since [hamster is a masculine noun according to RAE](https://dle.rae.es/h%C3%A1mster),  I always tend to use "el hamster" and use "el hamster hembra" if needed. "La hamster rubia" doesn't sound so bad however for many animals we do not change the gender of the noun. i.e "El zebro" "El culebro" "La cuerva" "El jirafo". All these sound weird specially when using the masculine form when the original noun is female.